# For all labeled regions in a matrix find their vertices for drawing

Tags: algorithm, matrix, graphics

I am looking for an algorithm that would get me data necessary for drawing  labeled regions of a matrix in a 3d application.

The input looks like this:

[image: labeled regions in a matrix]

For each region I need to find vertices of its outer boundary in CCW order.
I already can find the vertices of all horizontal or vertical edges by looking at the neighbours, but my implementation finds vertices from left to right, from top to bottom and not in the CCW order. Here is my code.

```
for (int i = 1; i < columns-1; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < rows - 1; j++) {
        if (grid[i][j] > 0) { // not background
            if ((grid[i + 1][j] != id) && (grid[i][j - 1] != id)) {
                getCellTopLeftCoord(i, j, &x, &y);
                polyPath[id]->Add(gcnew mPoint(x + width, y));
            }
            if ((grid[i - 1][j] != id) && (grid[i][j - 1] != id)) {
                getCellTopLeftCoord(i, j, &x, &y);
                polyPath[id]->Add(gcnew mPoint(x, y));
            }
            ... // etc..
```

here are the boundaries I am interested in:

[image: Boundaries of the labeled regions I am looking for]

Comment: How do you want to handle the 1 region, which is not simply connected?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I am interested in outer boundaries only, i.e., the polyline that encircles each region from the outside. I have added a sketch to my question.

Comment: So you're looking for the convex hull of each labeled region?

Comment: @beaker no, regions are not necessary convex, and I need the boundary polyline to be able to draw them accurately. They can assumed to be simply connected (i.e. region 2 cells also belong to the region 1) but not convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following procedure should work if there aren't any unconnected surfaces with repeated labels:

- Traverse the matrix from top to bottom and from left to right. If you encounter a non-null cell with a label that you haven't treated yet, create the path for that label.
- The point you have found is guaranteed to be a northeast corner. Put that point into your path.
- Now create a list of directions and start by going south. Because you are walking along the border anticlockwise, you should always have an occupied cell to the left and an unoccupied cell to the right. (Occupied here refers to a cell with the desired label.)
- When you try to find the next direction, continue in the last direction and check the cells to your right and left. if both are unoccupied, turn left. If at least the right one is occupied, turn right. Otherwise, continues straight on.
- When you change direction, append the current point to your path.
- Update the coordinates acording to the current direction. Repeat until you reach your original coordinates.

This method will not give you the diagonal lines around the area labelled 4 in your sketch; it will follow the axis-aligned jagged outline.

Here's an example implementation in Javascript. The cell data is contained in the two-dimensional array `m`. `cell` looks up a cell, but accounts for out-of bounds look-ups. `path` creates the path for a single label. `paths` creates a list of paths; it calls `path`:

```
function cell(x, y) {
    if (y < 0) return 0;
    if (y >= m.length) return 0;

    if (x < 0) return 0;
    if (x >= m[y].length) return 0;

    return m[y][x];
}

function path(x, y, c) {
    var x0 = x;
    var y0 = y;

    var res = [{x: x, y: y}];
    var dir = "s";

    var l, r;

    y++;

    while (x != x0 || y != y0) {
        var old = dir;

        switch (dir) {
        case "n":   l = (cell(x - 1, y - 1) == c) ? 1 : 0;
                    r = (cell(x, y - 1) == c) ? 2 : 0;
                    dir = ["w", "n", "e", "e"][l + r];
                    break;

        case "e":   l = (cell(x, y - 1) == c) ? 1 : 0;
                    r = (cell(x, y) == c) ? 2 : 0;
                    dir = ["n", "e", "s", "s"][l + r];
                    break;

        case "s":   l = (cell(x, y) == c) ? 1 : 0;
                    r = (cell(x - 1, y) == c) ? 2 : 0;
                    dir = ["e", "s", "w", "w"][l + r];
                    break;

        case "w":   l = (cell(x - 1, y) == c) ? 1 : 0;
                    r = (cell(x - 1, y - 1) == c) ? 2 : 0;
                    dir = ["s", "w", "n", "n"][l + r];
                    break;
        }

        if (dir != old) res.push({x: x, y: y});

        switch (dir) {
        case "n":   y--; break;
        case "e":   x++; break;
        case "s":   y++; break;
        case "w":   x--; break;
        }
    }

    return res;
}

function paths() {
    var res = {};

    for (var y = 0; y < m.length; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < m[y].length; x++) {
            var c = m[y][x];

            if (c && !(c in res)) {
                res[c] = path(x, y, c);
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I have just implemented it and it does exactly what I need.